# How do I install OpenJDK on Redhat Enterprise Linux on Azure and AWS environments?

Tags: linux, redhat

How do I install OpenJDK on Redhat Enterprise Linux on Azure and AWS environments?

I am a beginner server infrastructure engineer.

I have installed OpenJDK17 on Redhat Enterprise Linux on Azure and AWS environment, and I get the following error.

```bash
$ sudo dnf install java-17-openjdk
No match for argument: java-17-openjdk
Error: Unable to find a match: java-17-openjdk
```

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openjdk/17/html-single/installing_and_using_openjdk_17_on_rhel/index

If you install OpenJDK11, the installation is successful.

For RHEL, is it possible to install JDK17 without a Redhat subscription?

Do I need to change my OS to Ubuntsu or CentOS to install JDK17?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: Does this not work? [Install Java 11 (OpenJDK 11) on RHEL 8|CentOS 8|Rocky Linux 8](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-java-11-openjdk-11-on-rhel-8/) Or, I guess you want [Install Java 17 (OpenJDK 17) on Rocky Linux 8|CentOS 8/7](https://techviewleo.com/install-java-openjdk-on-rocky-linux-centos/) (not sure about 17 on RHEL)

Comment: Thank you. I was able to install it successfully.